# Could the sum of an even number of distinct positive odd numbers be divisible by each of the odd numbers?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Could the sum of an even number of distinct odd numbers be divisible by each of the odd numbers ?

Let $k\geq 4$ be an even number. Can one find $k$ distinct positive odd numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ such that each $x_i$ divides $S = \sum_{i=1}^k x_i$ ?

Is it possible at least for $k$ big enough ?

Comment: Incidentally this has a solution for k = 0 if you hadn't excluded it with k≥4

Comment: @Joshua guess why I excluded it, then...

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Divide your sum by $S$ and you have

$$1=\sum_i \frac {x_i}S$$

which is an Egyptian fraction expression of $1$ where all the denominators have the same number of factors of $2$.  This is known to be solvable with all denominators odd, but all known solutions have an odd number of terms.   A survey paper is [here](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fractions/egyptian.html#section9.5).  The section of interest is $9.5$.  One example is:

$$1=\frac 13+\frac 15+\frac 17 + \frac 19+\frac 1{11}+\frac 1{15}+\frac 1{35}+\frac 1{45}+\frac 1{231}$$

where the denominators have least common multiple $3465$ so we can write:

$$3465=1155+693+495+385+315+231+99+77+15$$

with every term dividing the sum.  Now if we add $3465$ to each side we have a solution with an even number of terms:

$$6930=3465+1155+693+495+385+315+231+99+77+15$$

Any Egyptian fraction decomposition of $1$ into fractions with odd denominators yields a solution to your problem.  The sum will be twice the least common multiple of the denominators in the decomposition.  The paper shows that there is such a decomposition for all odd numbers of terms $9$ or above.  You can multiply any solution by any odd number to get another.

What is happening is we are converting the Egyptian fraction decomposition of $1$ with all denominators odd into one that looks like $$1=\frac 12+\frac12\left(\text{all other terms}\right)$$